# how to select only particular value from Name

Tags: sql

i have a requirement to select only title from Name.
 in the Name how to separate only title value and pass as title.

```
First_name  Last_name Middle_Name    Full_Name                Title
NANCY        HEINICK   Null          HEINICK,NANCY MD
CHARLES      BONISKE    H            BONISKE,CHARLES H      
THOMAS        NEAL      W             NEAL,THOMAS W MD
```

In the above examples i need to select title and put it in title column if there is no title in full name i need is as NULL

Output

```
Title
MD
NULL
MD
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This isn't a free coding service. Please take the [tour], and especially read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the title is everything else, use `replace()` with a little extra logic:

```
select nullif(replace(replace(replace(replace(full_name, first_name, ''), last_name, ''), ',', ''), ' ', ''), '') as title
```

EDIT:

Because of the middle name (which I missed the first time around), it is better to concatenate all together and then replace:

```
select replace(full_name,
               (last_name || ',' || first_name ||
                coalesce(concat(' ', middle_name), '') || ' ',
               ), ''
              ) as title
```

Note that the code might vary slightly.  Not all databases support the standard `||` operator for string concatenation.

Comment: Hi Gordon thank you for reply  i am not getting correct because  the middle name is S and the middle name need to remove and return only MD. SMD FIELDS,LARRY S MD i need only MD.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select ltrim(replace(full_name, (last_name + ',' + first_name + coalesce(' ' + middle_name, '')), ''))
```